# Confusion in the graph of Maxwell Boltzmann distribution of speed

Tags: ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

So, I was reading about maxwell boltzmann distribution of speed and the function for fraction of molecules with a speed v was given as $$\frac{dN}{N}=4\pi \biggl[\frac{M}{2\pi RT}\biggr]^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{\frac{Mu^2}{2RT}}u^2du$$ But on the next page the graph was drawn with the y-axis as $\frac{1}{du}\frac{dN}{N}$ and x-axis as u. Why did we change the left hand side of funtion when plotting the graph?

I think this is done as by doing so we can easily get the fraction of molecules with speed u by taking the area under the graph but something feels amiss.

Am I right? If so then why and if wrong then could you please tell where i was going wrong.
Also, will there be any change in the graph if we take the y axis as $\frac{dN}{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your book is using this pseudo-infinitesimal notation $du$, and, seeing your confusion, is probably not formalising it or explaining it properly.

As I think you do understand, that equation means: there are $dN$ molecules with speeds between $u$ and $u+du$. This fraction is a function of $u$, so we can write:
$$ dN/N = f(u)du$$
However $du$ is an "infinitesimal" quantity, so we can't plot $dN$ versus $du$. However we can plot the probability distribution $f(u)$, which is what is actually interesting here. (It's a probability distribution because $\int f(u)du = \int \frac{1}{N}dN = 1$.)

You can also see $dN$ and $du$ as *measures*, using a different mathematical perspective, in which case $f$ is their Radon-Nikodym derivative. But I may be wrong, and anyway this is not going to help you.

Comment: Thank you.. I think I get where I went wrong now. But what are you saying in the last paragraph?

Comment: @aseemmittal It's a different mathematical formalization of that concept, but I also don't fully understand it so better we leave it to others...